# Using a dynamic variable in an ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, get

I'm struggling to pass a GET variable into a jquery file.

My code is

```
function upload(files){ // upload function
        var fd = new FormData(); // Create a FormData object
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Loop all files
            fd.append('file_' + i, files[i]); // Create an append() method, one for each file dropped
        }
        fd.append('nbr_files', i); // The last append is the number of files

        $.ajax({ // JQuery Ajax
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/tuto-dd-upload-image.php?order=5', // URL to the PHP file which will insert new value in the database
            data: fd, // We send the data string
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data); // Display images thumbnail as result
                $('#dock').attr('class', 'dock'); // #dock div with the "dock" class
                $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 100%').attr('aria-valuenow', '100').text('100%'); // Progress bar at 100% when finish
            },
            xhrFields: { //
                onprogress: function (e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        var pourc = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
                        $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: ' + pourc + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', pourc).text(pourc + '%');
                    }
                }
            },
        });
```

I need the 5 in `url: 'ajax/tuto-dd-upload-image.php?order=5'` to be the vatriable `order` passed through a url like `domain.com/?order=XX`

Comment: y r u not adding a <input type="hidden" name="order" value="5"> or `value="<?=$_GET['order']?>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP and export the variable:

```
var orderId = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['order']); ?>;

function upload(files) {
    ...
    url: 'ajax/tuto-dd-upload-image.php?order=' + orderId,
```

Or you could parse it directly in javascript:

```
var orderId = self.location.search.match(/order=(\d+)/)[1];

// Then continue like the previous example
```

Of course you'll probably need some error checking around this, if there's a chance the GET param might ever be missing.

Comment: I tried yesterday, but there was a time limit on marking the answer. Marked it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with javascript :

```
function $_GET(key){
    var result = new RegExp(key + "=([^&]*)", "i").exec(window.location.search); 
    return result && result[1] || ""; 
}
```

and call `$_GET(key)` function in your `$.ajax` request.

```
var order = $_GET('order');
url: 'ajax/tuto-dd-upload-image.php?order='+order,
```